Как скомпилировать .obj файл с++ (gcc)?
Я хочу скомпилировать объектный файл через gcc из кода на c++.
Я знаю что есть способ компиляции через asm, но он у меня он не работает, так вот: может есть какой-то флаг на подобии -E или -S, который сразу скомпилирует .obj?

этот флаг  -c.
